# Finding out that the output of my program is redirected into a file

Tags: c, linux, output

I want to know if it is posible in linux and C to find out that my programs output is redirected to a file.
I want to format the output human readable when it is printed on stdout `$ ./myprogram` and like csv when it is redirected to a file `$ ./myprogram >> data.csv`

is it posible?

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe with the argv/argc from main()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) function for that:

```
if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
{
    /* Standard out is an interactive terminal */
}
else
{
    /* Standard out is something else (pipe, file redirect, etc.) */
}
```

Comment: thanks, `if(isatty(fileno(stdout))){is a terminal}else{is a file};` :)